# Help for project on the basics of the Higgs field

Tags: resource-recommendations, standard-model, education, higgs, qft-in-curved-spacetime

I have a project for my university class on the [Higgs fields](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_field) and how it impacts the standard model. Also I was going to add some information on how the Higgs particle is formed and decays into particles with the probability of decay based on the mass of the particles.

I need resources that I can cite like papers that are beginner friendly that would describe how the Higgs field impacts the standard model in general and how it gives masses to elementary particles in the standard model.

(By beginner friendly I mean for someone who has introductory level knowledge of Quantum Field Theory but not at the level of a graduate student)

I also need a resources I can cite for on the Feynman rules for the Higgs vertices and how it interacts with other fields.

Also I am at the undergraduate level so you know what level papers I can read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All these links are accessible at a non-mathematical level, and they are by recognized scientists (with the exception of the first link).

(1) To start, see the "Simple English Wikipedia", which explains what the Higgs effect is, and the reason for the Higgs effect: http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_field.

(2) The difference between the Higgs boson and the Higgs field is in this short answer from Fermilab: http://www.fnal.gov/pub/science/inquiring/questions/higgs_boson.html.

(3) Here is a complete explanation of the Higgs field, the particle, and how the field works, written by a theoretical physicist: http://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/particle-physics-basics/how-the-higgs-field-works-with-math/.  Here is how it impacts the standard model: http://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/the-higgs-particle/the-standard-model-higgs/.

(4) From the Quantum Diaries website, here is an explanation of the Higgs boson with Feynman diagrams: http://www.quantumdiaries.org/2011/03/25/an-idiosyncratic-introduction-to-the-higgs/.  This is a more complete series of Feynman diagrams, which requires a good deal of attention: http://www.quantumdiaries.org/2011/05/05/a-diagrammatic-hint-of-masses-from-the-higgs/.  The Higgs boson in the vacuum: http://www.quantumdiaries.org/2011/06/03/higgs-and-the-vacuum-viva-la-vev/

(5) Instructions on how to explain the Higgs Mechanism to others, from a scientist's blog: http://www.preposterousuniverse.com/blog/2012/12/07/how-to-explain-the-higgs-mechanism/

(6) Here is another view, which also tries to explain the Higgs boson with a Feynman diagram.  It's interesting because the Lagrangian for the Standard Model is reproduced in full.  You can see all the math, and the Higgs part is circled in red, and explained: http://www.quantumdiaries.org/2012/09/13/higgs-problems/.  This is a good attempt to place the Higgs in the Standard Model, while keeping it accessible to non-mathematicians yet giving you a taste of the math.

Comment: Thanks a lot do you also know of any links that are somewhere in between a Graduate and Undergrad physics level. Like I understand Feynman diagrams and can understand Interacting  Lagrangians in QFT but I am only an undergrad in physics so my math is intermediate i.e I can understand the Fourier expansion of fields in four momentum space.

Comment: @FireFistAce: This paper was written by a PhD student at the University of Southern Denmark while he was an undergrad (scroll down to p. 17, then p. 22): http://cp3-origins.dk/content/thesis/2009-01-joergensen.pdf.  It dates before the LHC discovery of the Higgs particle, but it explains the Higgs mechanism as spontaneous symmetry breaking, and applies the Higgs mechanism to find masses.  It may be helpful, but I don't know if it's up-to-date.  This Q&A may be relevant to it: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/173955/why-are-we-allowed-to-spontaneously-break-the-higgs-field-symmetry